# How can I add customized icon link to Shopify header

Tags: shopify

I need help to add customized icon to the header of Shopify Store - Narrative theme.

https://butterflight-boutique.myshopify.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If no option available in theme settings then do below

**Note: You should have HTML code idea.**

From your Shopify admin, go to Online Store > Themes.

Find the theme you want to edit, and then click Actions > Edit code

Goto templates section and find Header template you can update there.

If the header is custom then to the main layout find which header is working and update that as per need.